# Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, x11-forwarding

I have installed visual studio code and dependencies to my ubuntu trusty OS in Oracle VM Ware. And I run code with these commands.

```
ssh -X myserver
code
```

But when i use mysql extension in code it gives me an error like

> Unknown or unsupported transport “disabled” for address “disabled:”

Here is a picture of the error.
[image: Problem]

I've googled it, Gave remote permissions to to all privileges and no luck. My MySQL server is on another VM and ubuntu server and vs-code is on another VM and I am working on the mother os.

Answer (score 1):

This means dbus isn't running.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120392